# How vitest mock different variable value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vitest

I want to test my react project array

```
// this method is in the utils.ts

export const platform = (
  navigator.userAgentData?.platform || navigator.platform
).toLowerCase()

export const keyboardPlayerShortcutsData = [
  {
    name: 'play/pause',
    shortcut: platform.startsWith('mac') ? `⌘ + p` : 'Ctrl + p',
  }
]
```

```
it('should generate correct keyboard player shortcuts data (mac)', () => {
  // need to mock "import { platfrom } from './utils'"

  expect(keyboardPlayerShortcutsData).toEqual([
    {
      name: 'play/pause',
      shortcut: '⌘ + p',
    },
  ])

  const shortcutElement = screen.getByText('⌘ + p')

  expect(shortcutElement).toBeInTheDocument()
})
it('should generate correct keyboard player shortcuts data (win)', () => {
   // need to mock "import { platfrom } from './utils'"

  expect(keyboardPlayerShortcutsData).toEqual([
    {
      name: 'play/pause',
        shortcut: 'ctrl + p',
    },
  ])

  const shortcutElement = screen.getByText('ctrl + p')

  expect(shortcutElement).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

I use `vi.mock('./utils', () => ({ platform: 'mac' }))` in each test, but `vi.mock` will hoist to the top, so the test will fail.

I also tried, but it also not work

```
import { platform } from './utils'

describe('EditKeyboardShortcutSheet', () => {
    vi.mock('./utils', () => ({
      platform: 'MacIntel'.toLowerCase(),
    }))
    
  afterEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks()
  })

  it('should generate correct keyboard player shortcuts data (mac)', () => {
    expect(keyboardPlayerShortcutsData).toEqual([
       {
        name: 'play/pause',
        shortcut: '⌘ + p',
      },
    ])
  })

  it('should generate correct keyboard player shortcuts data (win)', () => {
    // ref: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/4328
    // got an ts error: Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type 'string'.
    vi.mocked(platform).mockReturnValue('Windows')

    expect(keyboardPlayerShortcutsData).toEqual([
      {
        name: 'play/pause',
        shortcut: 'ctrl + p',
      },
    ])
  })
})
```